# Rails routes, more optimal routing scheme in this case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

(Background)

I have two view types to which all the requests map to, view1action, view2action.

For view1 type, the url may contain attributes 'a', 'b'.

For view2 type, the url certainly has attribute 'c' and may contain attributes 'a', 'b' and 'd'.

May I know if the route scheme I am using below is optimal.
I appreciate if someone can point to a better way.

```
  get '/(:a)', to: 'controller#view1action', default: { a: 'A', b: 'B' }
  get '(/:a)(/:b)', to: 'controller#view1action', default: { a: 'A', b: 'B' }
  get '(/:a)(/:b)/view2action/:c(/:d)', to: 'controller#view2action', default: { a: 'A', b: 'B', d: 0 }
```

Also, I am using console to see how the urls get mapped.

```
> r = Rails.application.routes
> r.recognize_path('/')
 => {:default=>{:a=>"A", :b=>"B"}, :controller=>"controller", :action=>"view1action"}
```

Why are the defaults ':a=>"A", :b=>"B" not part of the main hash and instead as a separate hash (:default) within the main hash?

Thanks.

Comment: This example is far too contrived for anybody to be able to give any meaningful advise.

Comment: Thank you. Tried to make the question more clear. Let me know if that helped.